# Cannot assign keyboard shortcut to Readibility for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, readability

Readability is a very convenient plugin for Chrome. I can reformat the page or send the page to Kindle.

When I reinstall the Chrome browser, I can neither use the keyboard shortcuts nor assign shortcut for it.

[image: This is the settings page for readibility]

When I click on the box and press some shortcuts, such as `ctrl-shift-k`, nothing happened.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by **reinstall** `Readability`.

The reason I leave this question without deleting it is for other's reference - maybe someone come across the same problem someday - he doesn't need to ask again.

Comment: I had the same problem. Reinstall worked for me as well.